# CKEditor 4.4.1 Empty anchor tag missing even when styled

Tags: ckeditor, anchor

We have been using empty anchor tags with css for years to allow hover states with no issues. Here is a sample of the css and html.

```
a#phone:link, a#phone:visited { width:34px; height:34px; display:inline-block; background:url(phone.png) center top no-repeat; }
a#phone:active, a#phone:hover { background:url(phone-hover.png) center top no-repeat; }
<a href="/contact.php" id="email" title="Contact Us"></a>
```

After a lot of digging I finally got cke to stop deleting my empty anchor tags, here is what I did if interested or helpful. I tried to set the removeEmpty but that didn't work until I added protectedSource:

```
config.contentsCss = '/css/editor.css';
config.protectedSource.push(/<a[^>]*><\/a>/g);
enterCKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.a = 0; code here
```

That finally prevented cke from deleting the tag, however the icons still does not appear in the wysiwyg editor. Its all there in code view...

I have stylesheetparser installed and the other styles in the linked css file are displaying correctly, including floating divs that have a width/max-width defined.

When I view the web page in Dreamweaver or a web browser, all the icons are there and working great, but the links/icons don't appear in cke. I can/have added a no-break space, but that adds margin/line-height, and just messes up the alignment design and layout.

What am I missing? Is this expected behavior?  I don't think it should be. Is this a bug?

Any thoughts/ideas/help? Thanks!